# How to support comparisons for QVariant objects containing a custom type?

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

According to the Qt documentation, `QVariant::operator==` does not work as one might expect if the variant contains a custom type:

> **bool QVariant::operator== ( const QVariant & v  ) const**
>
> Compares this QVariant with v and
>   returns true if they are equal;
>   otherwise returns false.
>
> In the case of custom types, their
>   equalness operators are not called.
>   Instead the values' addresses are
>   compared.

How are you supposed to get this to behave meaningfully for your custom types? In my case, I'm storing an enumerated value in a QVariant, e.g.

In a header:

```
enum MyEnum { Foo, Bar };

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyEnum);
```

Somewhere in a function:

```
QVariant var1 = QVariant::fromValue<MyEnum>(Foo);
QVariant var2 = QVariant::fromValue<MyEnum>(Foo);
assert(var1 == var2); // Fails!
```

What do I need to do differently in order for this assertion to be true?

I understand *why* it's not working -- each variant is storing a separate copy of the enumerated value, so they have different addresses. I want to know how I can change my approach to storing these values in variants so that either this is not an issue, or so that they do both reference the same underlying variable.

It don't think it's possible for me to get around needing equality comparisons to work. The context is that I am using this enumeration as the UserData in items in a `QComboBox` and I want to be able to use `QComboBox::findData` to locate the item index corresponding to a particular enumerated value.

Comment: Other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703835/qvariant-comparison-with-own-types-working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The obvious answer is to cast the data out of with `var1.value<MyEnum>() == var2.value<MyEnum>()` to compare them, but that requires you to know the type when comparing.  It seems like in your case this might be possible.

If you are just using enums, you could also convert it to an int for storage in the QVariant.

Edit: For clarification about searching a [`QComboBox`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qcombobox.html), it [uses the model of the combo box to find the data](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/widgets/qcombobox.cpp#line1490).  Specifically, it uses the [`match()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractitemmodel.html#match) function of the [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractitemmodel.html) to check for equality.  Luckily, this function is virtual so you can override it in a subclass.

Comment: The obvious answer doesn't work because I can't change what `QComboBox` does inside of its `findData` method. And yes, I know I could just store it as an int, but that seems inelegant. Plus, while I'm using an enum right now, I might want to use a class in the same way later, so I'm looking for a general solution.

Comment: Then you can override the `match()` function (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractitemmodel.html#match) in a model class and assign that to the `QComboBox` since that is how it does the comparisons for `findData` Edit: See here: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/widgets/qcombobox.cpp#line1490

Comment: That looks very promising. I'll come back and accept this answer if it works, once I get a chance to try it out.

Comment: Worked great! I subclassed `QStandardItemModel` with a class templated on type `T`, and re-implemented `match` so that if an exact match was being searched for and the variant to find was convertible to `T`, the `match` method would compare the `.value<T>()` of the variants rather than the variants themselves. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, not too long ago I realized QComboBox could reference QAbstractItemModel, it made many interfaces much easier!

Comment: I think that QComboBox is quite an underappreciated class. I've had exactly the same issue. They should spell it out in big letters, since it's not named like the other view classes are (QxyzView).

Answer (score 4):

Try hack qvariant, define the function by prototype

```
typedef bool (*f_compare)(const Private *, const Private *);
```

and set it to qvariant handler;
To work with qvariant qt use Handler:

```
struct Handler {
    f_construct construct;
    f_clear clear;
    f_null isNull;
  #ifndef QT_NO_DATASTREAM
    f_load load;
    f_save save;
 #endif
    f_compare compare;
    f_convert convert;
    f_canConvert canConvert;
    f_debugStream debugStream;
};
```

This example demonstrates how to hack qvariant debug  output and convert to string. This is very simple example, and you need to extend it for you problem. "Identifier" is my custom type.

```
class HackVariant : private QVariant
{
public:
     static void hackIt() {
         origh = handler;
         Handler* h = new Handler;
         *h = *origh;
         h->convert = convert;
         h->debugStream = hackStreamDebug;
         handler = h;
     }

private:
     static bool convert(const QVariant::Private *d, QVariant::Type t, void *result, bool *ok)
     {
         //qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "type:" << d->type;
         if (d->type >= QVariant::UserType)
         {
             QString& str = *((QString*)result);
             Identifier* ident = (Identifier*)(constData(d));
             str = ident->toString();
         }
         else
             return origh->convert(d, t, result, ok);
         return true;
     }

     static void hackStreamDebug(QDebug dbg, const QVariant &v) {
         if (v.canConvert<Identifier>())
             dbg << v.value<Identifier>();
         else
             origh->debugStream(dbg, v);
     }

     static const Handler* origh;

     static const void *constData(const QVariant::Private *d)
     {
         return d->is_shared ? d->data.shared->ptr : reinterpret_cast<const void *>(&d->data.ptr);
     }

};
```

You have to create function and set it to handler. Don't forget call `HackVariant::hackIt()` in main.cpp before use (var1 == var2).

Answer (score 4):

### Solution for Qt 5

Qt supports this out of the box since version 5.2. See [**QVariant::operator==**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#operator-eq-eq-1) and [**QMetaType::registerComparators**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#registerComparators).

### Solution for Qt 4

If you're still using Qt 4 and can't (or don't want) to upgrade to Qt 5 yet, you can use the **[CustomVariantComparator](http://pastebin.com/tNLa0jSa)** class which I've written up for one of my projects.

You can use it as follows. Let's say we have a class `Foo` which implements `operator==` and should be used within a `QVariant`:

```
class Foo {
public:
    bool operator==(const Foo &other) { return ...; }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo)
```

Then, simply put the `Q_DEFINE_COMPARATOR` macro next to the implementation of `Foo` (i.e. within the `Foo.cpp` file, but not within the `Foo.h` file):

```
Q_DEFINE_COMPARATOR(Foo)
```

Next, **after** constructing your `QApplication` (or `QCoreApplication`) instance, enable the custom variant comparator (this only has to be done once):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    CustomVariantComparator::setEnabled(true);
    // more code...
}
```

Now, the following code snippet will work as expected (i.e. invoke `Foo::operator==`).

```
QVariant::fromValue(Foo()) == QVariant::fromValue(Foo())
```